# Pandas does not find substring that includes parentheses

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find a substring within a specific Pandas `DataFrame` column. The substring and search string contain parentheses. When I use the built-in `.str.contains(substring)` method, Pandas does not find the substring even though it is clearly there. Consider the following minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

string = "Alice (Bob) Charlie Doris"
substr1 = "Alice (Bob) Charlie"
substr2 = "Alice"

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": (string,)})
print("Using regular Python:", substr1 in string, substr2 in string)
print("Using Pandas:")
print(df["col"].str.contains(substr1))
print(df["col"].str.contains(substr2))
```

Output:

```
Using regular Python: True True
Using Pandas:
0    False
Name: col, dtype: bool
0    True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Clearly, Pandas is only able to find the substring without parentheses (`substr2 = "Alice"`) but not the substring with parentheses (`substr1 = "Alice (Bob) Charlie"`), while regular Python is able to find both. Why does this happen?

Comment: Use `df["col"].str.contains(substr1, regex=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by default `Series.str.contains` uses a regex, and you even get a warning:

```
UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
```

"pattern", "match", "groups" are all red flags that mean "regex".

Also see [`Series.str.contains`'s docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), where the `regex`'s argument default value is `True`.

Either escape the parenthesis (so they don't create a capture group):

```
substr1 = "Alice \(Bob\) Charlie"
```

or pass `regex=False` to disable this behavior:

```
print(df["col"].str.contains(substr1, regex=False))
```